# Filter out list of code snippets visible on the list view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

Following [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926100) I have a set of code snippets.

But the snippet insertion has to be w.r.t the context, viz. if I do 'Insert Snippet' before declaring a class, it shouldn't show 'method declaration' snippet.
Also required is to filter snippets as per managed or unmanaged code.

In short I am looking for a mechanism as follows:

```
if <condition>
{
 modify list of snippets visible in the menu
}
```

Do we have such a mechanism or something similar? Ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question. Hope it helps someone.

I followed the instructions on the links:
[Video on Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc721667.aspx) & 
[Code Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171421%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Got the snippet.xml file to contain the following:

```
<Code Language="Language"
    Kind="method decl">
        Code to insert
</Code>
```

Then called the expansionProvider.DisplayExpansionBrowser in the FilterView class (refer to the video):

```
string[] kind = new string[1];                            
kind[0] = "method decl";
return expansionProvider.DisplayExpansionBrowser(TextView, 
                                                 snippets, 
                                                 null, false, kind, false);
```

Thus the specific snippet will appear in 'method declaration' context. Thus other snippets can be done. The xml has to hold the context information.